How do I categorized those who answered different options in google forms using google script in speadsheet?
I have a small business. I use google forms to record payments made by my clients. Now, since I’ve been having more and more clients, my work is getting much harder and harder. For my problem, I want a command script that can organize those who opted to only pay for International Shipping Fee, Local Shipping Fee, and for both. I’ve been getting confused lately because all answers are only recorded in 1 sheet which the google form and spreadsheet is linked on.
I’ve tried asking help for chatgpt but it always doesn’t work. I need a human support that could understand my problem better.

Welcome here! If you expect help here, you must show where you got stuck. Please create a sample GSheet which shows how your table looks like, also what you would like to achieve.
